# Remove drag and drop for selected cells

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-viewholder

I've created drag and drop for my recycler view, but I want disable drag and drop option on pull of cells (it's a headers in my view). How to make them not available for drag and drop function?

Drag And drop helper

```
class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(private val mAdapter: ItemTouchHelperAdapter) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
    override fun isLongPressDragEnabled() = true

    override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled() = true

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {}

    override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
        val dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
        val swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START or ItemTouchHelper.END

        return ItemTouchHelper.Callback.makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags)
    }

    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)

        return true
    }
}
```

Adapter for Recyclerview

```
interface ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): Boolean
}
```

Code to pair adapter to rv

```
val drugAndDropHandler = SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter)
ItemTouchHelper(drugAndDropHandler).attachToRecyclerView(multiple_stores_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just need to override `getMovementFlags`

```
override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
    if (viewHolder.adapterPosition in 0..NOT_DRAGABLE_ITEMS_MAX_POSITION) {
        return 0
    }
}
```